# Is it possible to have two virtual consoles open in a single screen?

Tags: 12.04, virtual-console

When using virtual consoles, is it possible to have two different virtual consoles open at the same time and sharing the screen space and being able to use either ?

Comment: Does this mean the PC/server must be in **text-only** mode, and you don't just want a multi-tab/session terminal capability?

Comment: @david6 Yes, you could say that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a tool that allows screen splitting like [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) to do that.Tmux is available on the repositories, and as per the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/tmux.1.html) you can use % to split the screen vertically and " to split it horizontally

[image]

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Does it run in a virtual console ? Documentation seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: As I understand it, each pane in effect is a virtual console. I know of people who use this over ssh, or on a cli only install, but yes, I do believe it should work

Comment: I will try it later today.

Comment: Its what I was looking for! Do you know any resource to learn the commands ? The man pages have too much information. How is Byobu ? Its also a multiplexerand seems to have more downloads from the Ubuntu Software center.

Comment: The man page really is the resource to use eventually https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tmux is a good start as would this http://blog.hawkhost.com/2010/06/28/tmux-the-terminal-multiplexer/

Comment: Using it for the past few days. It is far exceeding my expectations. Its awesome! Thanks :)